# Problem with ArgumentCaptor and consecutive call to same methods (bug or feature?)

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I'm having a problem with ArgumentCaptor not being able to record the 
arguments when calling the same method a number of times. 
Basically this does not seem to work:

```
List<Dummy> mList = mock(List.class);
Dummy dummy = new Dummy();
when(mList.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(dummy);

Dummy d = mList.get(12);
d.setName("John");
mList.add(d);

Dummy g = mList.get(10);
g.setName("Ben");
mList.add(g);
...

verify(mymock, times(3)).doStuff(captor.capture)); 
assertEquals("John", captor.getAllValues().get(0).getName()); 
assertEquals("Ben", captor.getAllValues().get(1).getName()); 
assertEquals("Don", captor.getAllValues().get(2).getName());
```

The value of getName() is always set to "Don". 
I have also tried using InOrder, with the same outcome.

Feature (and me stupiud) or bug?

To better explain the issue I have created a use case: 
http://pastebin.com/RE1UzJ4F

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

The java doc for ArgumentCaptor suggests what you are trying, so I'd say this is a bug. However, it is a bug in your code.

The problem is that you're changing the name of **the same** dummy each time you're invoking setName(..). I'd suggest that you make Dummy *immutable* and avoid setters wherever you can. That will avoid these types of bugs.

If you cannot make your Dummy immutable to force the issue you should at least pass a different instance from each get. Doing

```
when(mList.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(new Dummy(), new Dummy(), new Dummy());
```

Would fix the problem.

Comment: Yes, of course, the test code was just a way to explain the problem.

Comment: My point is that the only problem is in fact in your code, not in Mockito. Is that what you were trying to explain (in that case I'm sorry I missed it)?

Comment: I've fixed your sample in the pastebin (without compiling though).

Answer (score 2):

iwein is correct; however, there are some situations (such as embedded systems) in which memory is scarce and you do not want to use or cannot use immutability.

A workaround I have found is to use a different mock for each invocation, then verify a list of mocks that each have one invocation.

```
List<Mock> mocks = new ArrayList<Mock>();
...init list w/ mocks using for loop...
List<Object[]> expectedArgs = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
..init list w/ desired args...

mocks.get(0).callMethod(1, 2);
 ...do that some more...

for(int i = 0; i < mocks.size(); i++) {
     Object[] desiredArgs = expectedArgs.get(i);
     verify(mocks.get(i)).callMethod((int) desiredArgs[0], (int) desiredArgs[1]);
 }
```

It is not as pretty, but you do not have to make your classes immutable this way.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and ended up using `atLeastOnce`, like so:

```
private ActionRequest getRequestedAction() {
    ArgumentCaptor<ActionRequest> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(ActionRequest.class);
    verify(adapter, atLeastOnce()).requestAction(captor.capture());
    return captor.getValue();
}
```